# handle an inheritance hierarchy 3 levels deep with jpa

Tags: inheritance, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem with implementing inheritence in jpa. i have the following entities :

```
@Entity 
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable{
private String name;
private String }

@Entity 
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)    
public class User extends Person {
private String salary;}

public class chef extends User{}
```

I want all entities to be concrete ,is this correct or should I change something?

Comment: Seems ok, what is your issue?

Comment: I want to insert a user existing in table user in the table chef: User chef = new Chef();

chef = (User) dao.trouverPersonneParId("mark");
  
dao.ajout_createur(chef);                                             but I have this error :java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pfe.domaine.User cannot be cast to com.pfe.domaine.Chef

Comment: Can you post code about your dao? It seems there is a cast from `User` to `Chef` in some point, that's why I would like to see what you are doing to see if I can help you.

Comment: `here is my DAO :
public void ajout_createur(User d) 
{
 
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.persist(((Chef) d));
  em.getTransaction().commit();
  System.out.println(" CHEF ADDED!");
 }
`

Comment: In such case have you verified that, indeed, the object `d` is type of `Chef`? Is the `Chef` class also mapped as an entity? (I am not seeing that entity configuration in the `Chef` class?

Comment: A chef is a user, but a user is not neccesarily a chef.  You can't cast a user instance to a chef as you are doing in your persist call.

Comment: @Chris that's why I am asking if the object that is casting is of type `Chef`. It seems it is not... but I was trying to find more info to see if that's the root cause.

Comment: @ Angel Villalain yes the Chef class is mapped as an entity.@Chris you are right I can't cast a User to a Chef.

Comment: the joined inheritence strategy doesn't work between the two classes User and Chef. so I added an attribute in class User named Type. when a user becomes a chef Type is set Type to CHEF.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your User entry can be independent of the Chef table entry.  Java inheritance does not allow you to toggle an object to make it a different class - an object is either a User or a Chef.  JPA Joined inheritance follows the rules of Java inheritance, so the row in the Chef table is tied to the User table row as they are a single entity.

So if you have a User entity you can't make it a Chef entity.  What it sounds like you need is a User that can be assigned a role, such as Chef.  One way is to map the type field as you mentioned in the comment - but it will not give you access to the Chef table data - you still cannot use this to toggle the instance to become a Chef.  If you need the data, you might make User and Chef independent entities, and have User have a 1:1 mapping, say role, that can be assigned a Chef entity containing the relevant data and business rules.

Comment: ok thanks @Chris. the solution of 1:1 mapping is a good idea but for me I don't need to access the Chef table data